# Is there a built-in function for horizontal string concatenation?

Tags: c#

Given two files:

File1

> a a a
>   b b b
>   c c c

File2

> d d
>   e e

Bash has a command that will horizontally concatenate these files:

```
paste File1 File2
```

> a a a d d
>   b b b e e
>   c c c

Does C# have a built-in function that behaves like this?

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. I'm not asking for code. I'm asking if there is a built-in function that does this. This will help me determine if *I* need to write my own function to do it.

Comment: No, but it seems trivial to make one. Open each file, read a line from each file, concatenate the lines and write out to the new file.

Comment: @RonBeyer It *would* be trivial to make one, but why would I do that if one already exists?

Comment: I didn't say one existed, I'm saying one **doesn't** exist, which is why I said its trivial to implement.

Comment: @Rainbolt Because you haven't found one that already exists.  You've spent more time writing this question than it would have taken you to just implement this feature.

Comment: @Servy What if save the next few people who want to do this some time? Would that make the Internet a better place?

Comment: @Rainbolt If the function already existed then they would presumably just come across the documentation for it when searching, rather than your question.

Comment: @Servy Well, this wouldn't be the first time that I have tried and failed to find something on the Internet.

Comment: Probably that is not horizontal string concat, but adding 2d arrays in some weird way. Using LINQ ForEach should be a simple task, no need special function for that.

Comment: @alexsuslin LINQ has no ForEach method.

Comment: @Servy, partly true =)))

items.ToList().ForEach(i => i.DoStuff());

Comment: @alexsuslin It's not partly true, it's entirely true.  That's a method of `LIst`, it has nothing to do with LINQ.  And of course you could just use the `foreach` operator of the language itself; you're gaining nothing using that method (and costing yourself the effort spent needed to entirely pointlessly build and throw away a list).

Answer (score 1):

```
public void ConcatStreams(TextReader left, TextReader right, TextWriter output, string separator = " ")
{
    while (true)
    {
        string leftLine = left.ReadLine();
        string rightLine = right.ReadLine();
        if (leftLine == null && rightLine == null)
            return;

        output.Write((leftLine ?? ""));
        output.Write(separator);
        output.WriteLine((rightLine ?? ""));
    }
}
```

Example use:

```
StringReader a = new StringReader(@"a a a
b b b
c c c";
StringReader b = new StringReader(@"d d
e e";

StringWriter c = new StringWriter();
ConcatStreams(a, b, c);
Console.WriteLine(c.ToString());
// a a a d d
// b b b e e
// c c c
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `Zip()` wants files with *equals lengths*, so in case of *Linq* you have to implement something like that:

```
public static EnumerableExtensions {
  public static IEnumerable<TResult> Merge<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TFirst> first,
    IEnumerable<TSecond> second,
    Func<TFirst, TSecond, TResult> map) {

      if (null == first)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("first");
      else if (null == second)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("second");
      else if (null == map)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("map");

      using (var enFirst = first.GetEnumerator()) {
        using (var enSecond = second.GetEnumerator()) {
          while (enFirst.MoveNext())
            if (enSecond.MoveNext())
              yield return map(enFirst.Current, enSecond.Current);
            else
              yield return map(enFirst.Current, default(TSecond));

          while (enSecond.MoveNext())
            yield return map(default(TFirst), enSecond.Current);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Having `Merge` extension method, you can put

```
var result = File
  .ReadLines(@"C:\First.txt")
  .Merge(File.ReadLines(@"C:\Second.txt"), 
         (line1, line2) => line1 + " " + line2);

File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\CombinedFile.txt", result);

// To test 
Console.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Comment: Why ReferenceEquals? It's equivalent to `==` here.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Just a habbit (I've got a bitter experience with overloaded `==` and `Equals`). However, in case of `ReferenceEquals(null, ...)` you're quite right. I've edited the answer